# delete the closest li in the hierarchie in the success of ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, html-lists

i am trying to delete the closest li element. the thing is that there is loop which is creating the `li` elements with same id. this is fine so far, but there is another loop which is doing the same job. in each `li` element, there is a js delete function which takes the `id` of each each `li`. but now, if i click the `li` element of the second loop, it is deleting the first li in the first loop. my js code for the first loop is this:

```
function del_contact_a(cid){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/del_contact_a/",
            data: {id:cid},
            type: "POST",
        }).success(function(){
            $('#'+cid).closest('li').remove();
        })
}
```

js code for the second loop is this:

```
function del_contact_ver(cid){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/del_contact_ver/",
            data: {id:cid},
            type: "POST",
        }).success(function(){
            $('#'+cid).closest('li').remove();
        })
}
```

my both loops are these:

```
{% if contact_a %}
{% for ac in contact_a %}
<li id="{{ac.id}}"> <a> {{ac.name}} {{ac.nachname}}</a> <a onclick="del_contact_a({{ac.id}})"> <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/erase.png" /> </a>  </li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

..

```
{% if contact_a %}
{% for ac in contact_a %}
<li id="{{ac.id}}"> <a> {{ac.name}} {{ac.nachname}}</a> <a onclick="del_contact_ver({{ac.id}})"> <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/erase.png" /> </a>  </li>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

can someone give me clue please? thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same id on the 2 loops for your li.
You should use a prefixe on each one, depending on your loops.

The first one :

```
<li id="a-{{ac.id}}">
```

The second one :

```
<li id="ver-{{ac.id}}">
```

And change in you "" accordingly

An id, must be unique as its name suppose it :P

Additionaly, I don't understand why you are using the closest method ?

```
$('#'+cid).remove();
```

should be enough.